# Can't use Element.children when one of the child nodes has name="children"

Tags: javascript, dom

I noticed a strange problem when using [Element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) and don't seem to find a good work-around.

### Example 1 (expected behaviour)

Take  this HTML:

```html
<form>
  <input name="hi">
  <input name="bye">
</form>
```

And this JS

```js
const formElement = document.querySelector('form');
for (let i = 0; i < formElement.children.length; i++) {
  console.log(formElement.children[i].name);
}
```

The console prints the following, as you would expect:

```
"hi"
"bye"
```

### Example 2 (strange behaviour)

Now, let's add an input field with `name="children"`

```html
<form>
  <input name="hi">
  <input name="bye">
  <input name="children">
</form>
```

The console prints nothing.

### Why this happens in my opinion

`formElement.children` returns an *HTMLCollection*.
In an HTMLCollection you can access the child elements via an index, or directly by the name attribute of the element you are trying to target.

So in order to get the *"hi"* element, you could say `formElement.children[0]` or `formElement.hi`.

However when there is an element with the name `"children"` inside the collection, `formElement.children` will return the element with name="children", and there is no longer any way to loop trough all the elements.

### How do I work around this?

That's my question. I know I can simply not use the name "children" and choose something else instead, but surely there must be a way to make this work?

Here's a pen to illustrate the problem: https://codepen.io/pwkip/pen/XWVoXVE

---

EDIT:

this seems to be related to the fact that *formElement* is a `<form>`. When I change it to a `<div>`, things work. So I guess the question boils down to this:
**how do I convert a HTMLFormElement to regular HTMLElement?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because for quite unfortunate historic reasons, the HTMLFormElement has a [named property getter](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-supported-property-names), which [will return](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element:supported-property-names) the children `<input>` elements that have either their `.name` or their `.id` property value set to the given name. <sup>Actually it's more complex than that, but not that interesting.</sup>

In my humble opinion, that's a real quirk in the specs, but it can't be removed without breaking old websites, which is something specs authors don't really like.

So yes, this `named` getter will take precedence over any other getters inherited farther in the prototype chain.

If you really don't want to change your element's `name`, what you can do is to call the `Element.children` getter on your HTMLFormElement explicitely, or even simpler you can probably just use `.querySelectorAll("*")` (assuming you don't have an element with such name or id ;-)

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");

console.log("with .children:", form.children); // our <input>

const getter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "children").get;
console.log("with Element's getter:", getter.call(form)); // an HTMLCollection

console.log("with querySelectorAll:", form.querySelectorAll("*")); // a NodeList
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="foo">
  <input name="children">
</form>
```